# How do I merge dataframes within R matching its row values?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, merge, rows

I have 6 data frames which I aggregated from more than 200 Excel files: there were 6 `.zip` files with Excels, each `zip` was named as "data1", "data2" and so on. Within `zips` there were Excels, named data1_unit1, data1_unit2, ..., data1_unit150. And so on. This information is crucial, see next section.

The structure of each Excel-file is the following

```
### data1_unit1
### Factor  Question  Positive  Neutral  Negative
###   1     Question1   62        33       18
###   2     Question2   48        13       84
```

I need to receive the following merged data frame

```
### mainDF
### Factor  Question  data1_unit1 positive  data1_unit1 neutral  data1_unit1 negative ... data6_unit48 negative
###   1     Question1    62                       33                   18             ...       95
###   2     Quesiotn2    48                       13                   84             ...       63
```

The main problem is that all of these 6 data frames have got the different length, and I need the values to match all the rows.

So, I want to make my Excel-files names and their contents as the columns.

I tried to do

```
mainDF <- do.call("cbind", list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6))
```

But it doesn't work because of the difference in length.

Comment: I would recommend adding a column to each `df` that indicates its unit. Then, bind the rows together and use `tidyr::pivot_wider`. If you create some actual sample data for multiple `dfs` I can write an answer if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm stuck. Can you help me? `df1 <- data.frame(factor = c(1:10),
                  question = c(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6,
                               q7, q8, q9, q10),
                  pos = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 16, 17,
                          18, 19, 20),
                  neu = c(20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 16, 15,
                          15, 14, 13, 12),
                  negative = c(67, 68, 69, 70, 71,
                               72, 73, 74, 75, 76),
                  unit = "unit1"
  
)`

Comment: When you say different length, you mean different number of rows? And what is the exact output that you want? You want the name of each dataframe as suffix to the names of columns? And do all of the dataframes have Factor and Question columns? Meaning you want them to math based on those columns?